# HighCharts - HeatMap - big Amount of Data with websocket

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to add a lot of data to a Heatmap type High-Charts graph,
data comes from WebSocket every 200ms

I made a small application to test: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44p52cha/)
I am able to add data to this graph but the more data I add, the longer the graph takes to update

```js
function ajouter(data) {
    let newData = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 33; index++) {

        newData = newData.concat([
            [numScan, (index), getRandomInt(2048)]
        ])
    }

    let oldData = graph.series[0].data
    let totalData = oldData.concat(newData)

    var xAxis = graph.xAxis[0];
    xAxis.setCategories(xAxis.categories.concat(numScan + 1))

    graph.series[0].setData(totalData)
    numScan++
}

function ajouterN(n) {
    let compteur = 0;
    const intervalleId = setInterval(() => {
        compteur++
        ajouter()
        if (compteur == n) {
            clearInterval(intervalleId)
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use the boost module https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module? Also, consider adding points via addPoint method which is suitable for dynamic data scenarios https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/dynamic-update